# How to run loopback test with two nic in Linux

Tags: networking, loopback

I have two nic in my Linux and I want to run some loopback test (packets sent out from one nic and received from the other). I have extra switch and/or router available but I don't want to use fancy features such as source NAT.

It seems easy at the first glance but I have tried to put the two nic in the same subnet and in different subnets with static routes. But none of them worked.

This is a quite common scenario but I can't find any working solution online. Can anyone help? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use network namespace to solve the problem